# Eloquent order relationship results

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a simple eloquent query and want to include another table with my results, however, the order of relationship results is incorrect.

Is it possible to order the results without using an `SQLRAW` statement

```
$groups = AttributeGroup::with('attribute')->where('page_id', $page->id)->get();
```

What I would like -

```
$groups = AttributeGroup::with('attribute')->orderBy('iteration', 'DESC')->where('page_id', $page->id)->get();
```

I get the error of `Unknown column` because this column is part of relationship table.

Comment: You want to order the *attribute* relation results?

Comment: Sorry updated to be more clear. Yes I wish to order the relation results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will order each *attribute* relation of every *attribute group* result:

```
$groups = AttributeGroup::with(['attribute' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('iteration', 'DESC');
}])->where('page_id', $page->id)->get();
```

Is this what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use closures to change the query when using `with` and `has`.

```
$groups = AttributeGroup::with(['attribute' => function($query){
    $query->orderBy('iteration');
})->where('page_id', $page->id)->get();
```

Details are available on https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads